# Error when starting new React Native Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npx

I'm following the setup instructions from the React Native [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) page, on my M1 Macbook Pro. I have previously worked on React projects and was able to create and run React Native Expo projects previously on the same machine.

I followed the instructions to the letter, but when I arrived at the '[Create A New Application](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#creating-a-new-application)" section, using the `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` command, the new project creation failed. Here are the error message outputted on the Terminal:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.66.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@6.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/cli@"^6.0.0" from react-native@0.66.4
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.69.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! react-native@"0.69.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.0.0" from react-native@0.69.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!     react-native@"0.69.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried to uninstall react-native and install it back but couldn't find a proper instruction on the net to do that. How can I just scrape the previously installed react-native (judging from the error message, i got RN@0.66.4, when I want to use the latest RN) and install a fresh, latest react native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are on Mac and your node version is 18.*.* which Is latest but not greatest.. you need to download 16.*.* the stable one.

Step-1

```
brew uninstall node; 
# or `brew uninstall --force node` which removes all versions
brew cleanup;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

Step 2 - and install it from node site by downloading the binary

Step 3 -  just check the node version again if you have 16.*.*
then you can try creating the react native project once again.
Please let us know if it worked for you. Wish you luck!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the answer suggests, you can do `brew install node@16` to install this particular version instead of manually downloading the binary.

Answer (score 0):

If installing node version 16 doesn't work for you ensure you update npm by running `sudo npm update -g`.